# node-postgres listen/notify gets timed out

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to implement notify triggers in postgres , also using node-postgres to listen to db changes .

```
var pgConnection = 'postgres://' + DB_USER + ':' + DB_PASSWORD + '@' + 
DB_HOST + ':' + DB_PORT + '/' + DB_NAME;

const pgClient = new pg.Client(pgConnection);
pgClient.connect();
pgClient.query('LISTEN leadupdated');
pgClient.query('LISTEN leadadded');
pgClient.on('notification', function (data) {
  console.log(data.payload);
  socket.emit(data.channel);
});
```

the script listens to changes for about 5-10 mins , but if inactive for sometime, it does not receive any db changes after that. How can i fix this timeout issue?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever manage to solve this, please?